# Change a href on click to go to url with string of current url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Trying to do the following:

1) User is on page: `https://www.example.net/value1/value2/value3/catid,xy somepages have value of catid=xy/value4/value5/value6/` - Category page

2) User clicks on LINK `<a href="https://www.example.net/index.php?valuexyz&(******input value of cat id on the page im on now***)"></a>`

I would like user on page `catid,xy` to click LINK and the URL string of `catid,ab` in the `href` to be automatically replaced with `xy` onclick.

Or redirected to page: `https://www.example.net/index.php?valuexyz&catid,xy` on click.

Simply put I want to have the URL string of `catid` change based on current page cat id.

```
      <script>
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("catid") > -1) {
        {
        document.getElementById("PostingAd").onclick HERE == window.location.href = 'https://www.example.net/index.php?value1value2value3&.catid';
        }</script>
```

I don't know how to include catid as it keeps changing on every page

NOTE: CATID is not necessarily xy or 12 or xyz it can be 1029 or 123 or hello etc.... also... Catid can be in format of "catid=" and "catid,"

UPDATE TO BE MORE CLEAR

they all have a cat id all i am asking is if im on URL 1 and i click on BUTTON x the button will direct me (the guy browsing on URL 1 = "www.example.com/blblblblblblblsaomasmadkasmdkfsdfsm/VALUE/slkfmsdlkfnlskdf" ) to URL b which is (www.example.com/kmfmksafmdalkf?dslf/VALUE/" for value to change based on url i am on

Comment: Try JavaScript's location.href = "url"; and just put in inside a function and pass the function inside the onclick or something - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include the code that you have tested so far. What have you tried? We don't care if it doesn't work, because then this question wouldn't exist.

Comment: Added what I tried ....

Comment: `&catid,ab` is not a valid URL search parameter - perhaps you mean `&catid=ab` ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks.... I did research for literally hours going from post to post before asking this question and couldn't find a solution with my limited knowledge of coding. I posted here what I tried and issue im having.

Comment: I posted that comment as your question originally showed no effort on your part, nor any code for us to debug. I've removed it now, as you've edited the question to enable us to help you more effectively.

Comment: @mplungjan Don't ask..........site is on Joomla 1.0 ..... Separate discussion but yes that is my URL structure.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you....wasn't trying to be rude....Just saying that much time was spent on my part before asking so it was kind of like......that's upsetting to read lol

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
const siteURL = "https://www.example.net/value1/value2/value3/catid,xy/value4/value5/value6/"; // location.href
const siteCatId = siteURL.split("catid,")[1].split("/")[0];
document.getElementById("someContainer").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // remove when live
  var tgt = e.target; 
  if (tgt.tagName==="A") {
    if (tgt.href.indexOf("&catid") !=-1) {
      tgt.href = tgt.href.replace(/catid([=|,]).*?$/g,function (match,oper) { 
      console.log(match,oper)
        return "catid"+oper+siteCatId;
      })
      console.log(tgt.href)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="someContainer">
  <a href="https://www.example.net/index.php?valuexyz&catid=ab">CHANGES - catid=ab -> catid=xy</a><br/>
  <a href="https://www.example.net/index.php?valuexyz&catid,abc">CHANGES - catid,abc -> catid,xy</a><br/>
  <a href="https://www.example.net/index.php?valuexyz&nocatid">This link does not change</a>
</div>
```

NOTE if your URL has catid= then use URLSearchParams instead

Comment: So i tried this code. Thank you very much. The issue is that it opens the url i put in the ahref....Also it's not a "," in second url its "=" i tried replaced it but doesnt work either. Keep in mind that in the ahref I cannot put a value to catid because i expect that value to change based on current url cat id

Comment: You need to replace `const siteURL = "https://www.example.net/value1/value2/value3/catid,xy/value4/value5/value6/";` with `const siteURL = location.href;` AND make sure that your strings match the real world

Comment: Did you change someContainer to whatever is wrapping your links? Does the console show the correct link?

Comment: yep I did that....It doesn't work.....in the ahref i put catid= is that currect? as i need that value to change based on current location.

Comment: No that is incorrect. It is not matching the spec we already discussed

Comment: I am replacing the catid,xx at the end of the url. If you change the format you need to change the regex

Comment: thanks so much for your help....I will try to play a bit now but heres the thing the catid url is: /catid,xy/ the url that redirected to is catid=xx at the end....The cat id changes on cat page when im there and when i click on the ahref i want catid of the current page to be there....

Comment: I changed the example - please change the question to reflect the format of the URLs

Comment: i changed the question to explain to the best of my abilities. I am trying the codes but they don't work. Redirects me to catid=ab or nocatid

Comment: Did you SEE the above example? It redirects ONLY the first and it redirects that one to `https://www.example.net/index.php?valuexyz&catid=xy`  - the second link is there to show it does NOT change because it does not HAVE a catid

Comment: they all have a cat id all i am asking is if im on URL 1 and i click on BUTTON x the button will direct me (the guy browsing on URL 1 = "www.example.com/blblblblblblblsaomasmadkasmdkfsdfsm/VALUE/slkfmsdlkfnlskdf" ) to URL b which is (www.example.com/kmfmksafmdalkf?dslf/VALUE/" for value to change based on url i am on

Comment: You have to a) show the correct code and b) implement my code correctly - I cannot fix your code if your question is not correct

Comment: <div  id="someContainer" style="display: inline-block; float: left; "  >
             <a style="display: inline-block; float: left; " href="https://www.example.net/index.php?valuesvaluesvalues&catid=ab"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Post an Ad in this category</span></a>
             </div>

Comment: <script>
const siteURL = location.href;
const siteCatId = siteURL.split("catid,")[1].split("/")[0];
document.getElementById("someContainer").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  var tgt = e.target; 
  if (tgt.tagName==="A") {
    if (tgt.href.indexOf("&catid") !=-1) {
      tgt.href = tgt.href.replace(/catid=.*?$/g,function (match) { 
        return "catid="+siteCatId 
      })
      console.log(tgt.href)
    }
  }
})
</script>

Comment: See update. I replace =ab with =xy and replace ,abc with ,xy

Comment: why are there 2 links? just 1 link. the current page i am on if value is hello in url ""catid=hello" or "catid,hello"  Menaing if that is what is contained on the page i am actually on in the url. then the button should take me to another page but the value of catid change based on page i was on when i clicked the button.... the button is static on like 100 category pages.

Comment: were not on the same page. idk how to explain it other than how i did. i tried....i do appreciate ur help

Comment: I only have your explanations to work on and you have changed those explanations several times since the original question which still does not show in detail input and expected output  - at least not in such a way it corresponds with your later narratives in your comments

Comment: This is for example SUPER unclear `UPDATE TO BE MORE CLEAR

they all have a cat id all i am asking is if im on URL 1 and i click on BUTTON x the button will direct me (the guy browsing on URL 1 = "www.example.com/blblblblblblblsaomasmadkasmdkfsdfsm/VALUE/slkfmsdlkfnlskdf" ) to URL b which is (www.example.com/kmfmksafmdalkf?dslf/VALUE/" for value to change based on url i am on`

Comment: I am not a coder I tried to be as clear as I can....I put ur code just as you said and in the url i put catid=ab and it redirects me to literally catid=ab........it doesnt change it

Comment: why is it so unclear .... URL of ahref go to a place with a catid which is the same in the url where u click from...... (the page ur currently on is "/catid=-,928384/" so /catid....../ of ahref changes to the same one that is on the current page..... just the catid/ section comma = + - if there is /catid.../ it replaces that on the url of ahref

Comment: Because you now suddenly have VALUE inside the PATH but you wanted to change catid=VALUE or catid,VALUE depending on which comment I read

Comment: I copied your code word for word minus the things that obviously wouldnt work and it seem to work i put catid=ab just like ur example in ahref

Comment: I am looking for `&catid` and not /catid/ so yeah